# video.js - find the start time of a seek during playback

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I am using video.js (http://www.videojs.com/) to build a video approval system and need to log user actions in the player. I can do this easily enough with play, pause, end etc. but have hit a problem when trying to log seeks.

I want to be able to log the start and end times of any seeks within the plaback, so we know if the user has not actually watched a section of the video. The player seems to offer events to support this, but I am struggling to get correct timings from it.

When the user skips through a video the player emits the following events in order: pause, seeking, seeked, play.

If I query the player object at any of these events using currentTime() the result is always the end time for the seek, even on the initial pause event. This means I can log where the seek ended but not where it started.

Can anyone help me to find the position in the video where the seek begins?

If this is not possible, I'd settle for a way to disable seeking during playback.

EDIT: adding code as requested. It's pretty simple:

```
var trackedPlayer = videojs('pvp-player');

trackedPlayer.on("play", function (e) {
    console.log("Video playback started: " + trackedPlayer.currentTime());
});

trackedPlayer.on("pause", function (e) {
    console.log("Video playback paused: " + trackedPlayer.currentTime());
});

trackedPlayer.on("seeking", function (e) {
    console.log("Video seeking: " + trackedPlayer.currentTime());
});


trackedPlayer.on("seeked", function (e) {
    console.log("Video seek ended: " + trackedPlayer.currentTime());
});

trackedPlayer.on("ended", function (e) {
    console.log("Video playback ended.");
});
```

If I can get all the tracking I want I will replace console.log with ajax calls to store the data.

Comment: Can you show us some code of where and how you attach the event handlers to the player?

Answer (score 7):

You can listen to `timeupdate` und take the next to last value you got there before `seeking` is called as your source:

```
var previousTime = 0;
var currentTime = 0;
trackedPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
    previousTime = currentTime;
    currentTime = trackedPlayer.currentTime();
});
trackedPlayer.on('seeking', function() {
    console.log('seeking from', previousTime, 'to', currentTime, '; delta:', currentTime - previousTime);
});
```

This seems to work with the HTML5 tech. I have not tested with other techs.

There is, however, one glitch: the first time seeking a *paused* player yields only a small delta (and the almost-same previous value for both variables). But this shouldn’t matter much since the delta is only a few hundred milliseconds (and I gather you’re only interested in the “from” value).

**Update**

`seeked` is triggered far more infrequently than `seeking`. Try the following.

```
var previousTime = 0;
var currentTime = 0;
var seekStart = null;
trackedPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
    previousTime = currentTime;
    currentTime = trackedPlayer.currentTime();
});
trackedPlayer.on('seeking', function() {
    if(seekStart === null) {
        seekStart = previousTime;
    }
});
trackedPlayer.on('seeked', function() {
    console.log('seeked from', seekStart, 'to', currentTime, '; delta:', currentTime - previousTime);
    seekStart = null;
});
```

There are also many libraries for debouncing function calls (in this case the call to your backend).

Comment: I've been playing with this; when the user drags the slider a whole boat load of entries are generated - timeupdate can fire as often as every 15ms, which generates far too many events when the user is scrubbing through a 30-minute video - certainly not practical once every event is an ajax call :)
Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find the same value for a project I was working on so I could determine whether or not a user was skipping forward or backward in a videojs player.

Initially, I thought to save the currentTime() a user was seeking **from** on **timeupdate** then immediately removing my timeupdate listener once **seeking** was dispatched. While this worked in some browsers like Chrome, unfortunately, I found that other browsers continued to fire timeupdate more frequently and would continue to update the currentTime() I was saving after the player actually seeked.

Here was the solution that ultimately worked across Safari/Chrome/Firefox. I have yet to test in IE.

```
var previousTime = 0,
    currentTime = 0,
    completeTime = 0,
    position = 0;


trackedPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
    previousTime = currentTime;
    currentTime = Math.floor(player.currentTime());

    // save 'position' so long as time is moving forward with each update
    if (previousTime < currentTime) {
        position = previousTime;
        previousTime = currentTime;
    }
});

// when seeking starts
trackedPlayer.on('seeking', function() {
    player.off('timeupdate', onTimeUpdate);

    player.one('seeked', onSeekComplete);
});

// when seeking completes
trackedPlayer.on('seeked', function() {
    completeTime = Math.floor(player.currentTime());
    console.log("User came from: " + position);
    console.log("User ended at: " + completeTime);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this is the only solution that worked for me.

```
var counter = 0;
var beforeTimeChange = 0;

function handleSeeking() {
  var timeoutTime = 300;
  var beforeCounter = counter + 1;
  if (trackedPlayer.cache_.currentTime === trackedPlayer.duration()) {
    return;
    // when video starts over, calls seek
  }
  beforeTimeChange = beforeTimeChange || trackedPlayer.cache_.currentTime;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (beforeCounter === counter) {
        console.log('before seek', beforeTimeChange, '\nafter seek', trackedPlayer.currentTime() - (timeoutTime / 1000));
        counter = 0;
        beforeTimeChange = 0;
    }
  }, timeoutTime);
  counter++;
}

trackedPlayer.on('seeking', handleSeeking);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more accurate solution, you can listen to the events that trigger the seek such as mousedown on progress bar, left key, right key etc., and get the current time from these events.
For example in version 7.10.2 you can do the following,

```
let seekStartTime;

player.controlBar.progressControl.on('mousedown', () => seekStartTime = player.currentTime());
player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.on('mousedown', () => seekStartTime = player.currentTime());
player.on('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
         seekStartTime = player.currentTime();
    }
});

console.log(seekStartTime);
```

**Note 1:** There are two seperate mousedown event listeners for progress control and seek bar. This is because the video can be seeked by clicking outside the seek bar on the progress control as well.

**Note 2:** Seeking using hotkey numbers does not pause the video. However, if necessary you can add those keydown listeners too.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find the start and end of a seeking action in my project and I used @Motorcykey answer and it worked, but there was a small bug. when I tried to seek to a time before the current time while the player was paused, the `position` didn't get updated. so I added just one line and it fixed it. I've tried other solutions too but so far this was the best solution that I've found. Here's the code snippet on player 'seeked'

```
player.on('seeked', function () {
    completeTime = Math.floor(player.currentTime());
    console.log("User came from: " + position);
    console.log("User ended at: " + completeTime);
    position= Math.floor(player.currentTime())
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this code to know the length of video.

```
var duration = document.getElementById("duration");
var vid_duration = Math.round(document.getElementById("video").duration);
    //alert(vid_duration);
duration.innerHTML = vid_duration;
    //duration.firstChild.nodeValue = vid_duration;
```

Comment: The question was about finding out the position of the playhead before seeking was started and has nothing to do with the duration.

Comment: @Raphael Schweikert, my bad :)