# Javascript function to detect if user jump/forward time in html5 player

Tags: javascript, html, video-player

How to detect if user jump/forward time in html5 player. I can only access current time but cannot detect if user skip video time.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743729/video-js-find-the-start-time-of-a-seek-during-playback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two events that you can make use of:

- `seeked`: Fires when the user is finished moving/skipping to a new position in the audio/video
- `seeking`:   Fires when the user starts moving/skipping to a new position in the audio/video

For example:

```
var video = document.getElementById("your_video_id");
video.onseeked = function() {
    alert("User jump or forward time");
};
```

Comment: hi thanks for solution but i am using videojs and your solution is not working with videojs player.