# use handleSeeked() function in videojs

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js

I'm using videojs to play videos on the site and I'm trying to create log on video streams but I have difficulty logging users seeking in videos. I need seek start and end time and it seems that the built in `handleSeeked`() function in videojs does the job but I can't get it to work. Does anybody know how to use this function?

**Update**

It seems that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743729/video-js-find-the-start-time-of-a-seek-during-playback) is about the same problem but the solutions aren't fully working and each one has a little problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted with the following code but I had to handle everything on my own so if there's still a better way to do this I'd be happy if you could help me.

```
    var previousTime = 0,
    currentTime = 0,
    completeTime = 0,
    position = 0;

player.on('timeupdate', function () {
    previousTime = currentTime;
    currentTime = Math.floor(player.currentTime());

    // save 'position' so long as time is moving forward with each update
    if (previousTime < currentTime) {
        position = previousTime;
        console.log('pos',position)

        previousTime = currentTime;
        console.log('pre',previousTime)
    }
});

player.on('seeked', function () {
    completeTime = Math.floor(player.currentTime());
    console.log("User came from: " + position);
    console.log("User ended at: " + completeTime);
    position= Math.floor(player.currentTime())
});
```