# Seeking and Seeked events are triggering together

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project in which I have to save every action of the user while watching video such as: where did he stopped, how much time he watched the video, when did he started and ended seeking.
I've almost done everything but the problem is, seeking and seeked event are both triggering together. Then how would I get the start and end time of the seek.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video controls src="sample.mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const sendRequest = (operation, data = false)=>{
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('operation', operation);
    if(data !== false) formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
    return fetch('https://www.example.com/operations.php', {method: 'post', body: formData});
};

// Video Analytics Start

const video = document.querySelector('video');
let playPauseStatus = {};
let videoWatchTime = 0;
let watchingVideo = false;
let seekStatus = {};

video.addEventListener('play', ()=>{
    playPauseStatus.play = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
    watchingVideo = true;
});
video.addEventListener('pause', ()=>{
    playPauseStatus.pause = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
    watchingVideo = false;
    sendRequest('4', playPauseStatus).then(()=> playPauseStatus = {});
});
video.addEventListener('seeking', ()=>{
     seekStatus.start = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
     watchingVideo = false;
});
video.addEventListener('seeked', ()=>{
     seekStatus.end = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
     sendRequest('5', seekStatus).then(()=> seekStatus = {});
});

setInterval(()=>{
    if(watchingVideo === true) videoWatchTime += 0.5;
}, 500);

// Video Analytics End


// Pushing Analytics Start

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', ()=>{
    if(document.visibilityState === 'hidden'){
      sendRequest('6', {'video_watch_time' : videoWatchTime});
    }
    video.pause();
});

// Pushing Analytics End
```

I don't want to use any plugin or library for this.
If anyone can tell me what am I missing.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can be of help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743729/video-js-find-the-start-time-of-a-seek-during-playback

Comment: @KostasMinaidis Thanks for your reply. I've tried those things but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLMediaElement` has a Boolean `seeking` attribute which is changed to `true` when the user begins seeking through the video. The `seeking` event is repeatedly fired while this is taking place. The `seeked` event is fired when the seeking ends and the `seeking` attribute is changed to `false`.

If you want to observe how frequently the `seeking` event is fired you can add a simple event handler and observe the browser console as you seek through a video.

```
video.onseeking = (event) => {
  console.log(`seeking: ${video.seeking}`);
};
```

You wish to determine the moment that the `seeking` began. In the following code segment this is done by using a Boolean attribute `isSeeking` that is initialised as `false` and is used as a guard condition in the event handlers.

When the `seeked` event fires, the content of the `seekStatus` object is logged to the console. You can change this functionality to meet your requirements.

```
const seekStatus = { start: null, end: null, isSeeking: false };

const seekingHandler = () => {
  if (!seekStatus.isSeeking) {
    seekStatus.start = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
    seekStatus.end = null;
    seekStatus.isSeeking = true;
  }
};

const seekedHandler = () => {
  if (seekStatus.isSeeking) {
    seekStatus.end = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
    seekStatus.isSeeking = false;
    // Avoid needless events being recorded
    if (seekStatus.start != seekStatus.end) {
      console.log(seekStatus);
    }
  }
};

video.addEventListener('seeking', seekingHandler);

video.addEventListener('seeked', seekedHandler);
```

**Note:** The `currentTime` property specifies the current playback time in seconds, so `Math.floor(video.currentTime)` is removing the millisecond accuracy of the value.

**EDIT:** The following code will smooth out the calls to the `seeked` handler by wrapping the event handler. The closure uses the `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` functions to determine whether sufficient time has passed between calls to handle the event. The timeout delay is set to 300ms which should be sufficient for your use case, but feel free to experiment with the value.

```
const debounce = (functionName, delay) => {
        let timeoutHandle = -1;
        return (...args) => {
          if (timeoutHandle !== -1) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
          }
          timeout = setTimeout(functionName, delay, ...args);
        };
      };

const debouncedSeekedHandler = debounce(seekedHandler, 300);

video.addEventListener('seeked', debouncedSeekedHandler);
```

Here's an alternative solution that avoids using timeouts. The handler is only invoked at most once per every `wait` milliseconds.

```
function throttle(functionName, wait) {
  let last = window.performance.now();

  const throttled = function(...args) {
    const now = window.performance.now();

    if (now - last >= wait) {
      functionName(...args);
      last = now;
    }
  };

  return throttled;
}

const throttledSeekedHandler = throttled(seekedHandler, 300);

video.addEventListener('seeked', throttledSeekedHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's still triggering seeking and seeked at almost same time. If a user seeks slowly then it's making the start and end time the same. Screenshot of console: https://snipboard.io/edwiga.jpg

Comment: The logic within the `seekedHandler` function can be modified to not record the event if both the `start` and `end` attribute values are the same.

Comment: Thanks bro! We are getting closer. Now the only problem is, its triggering the seeked event even when the seeking isn't done.

Comment: The `seeked` event isn't cancelable so you would have to engineer a way to make it possible to do so. One method would be to create a wrapper function to debounce the event handler using a timer.

Comment: If we use the debounce technique then we are already bound to the timer.

Comment: You can avoid using a timer by measuring the difference between timestamps before calling the event handler. I've added a `throttle` function to my answer to demonstrate such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the APIs that are available to us aren't designed in an optimal way for our data structures or use cases.

You said:

> I don't want to use any plugin or library for this.

which means that you'll have to write some code to correlate the time values corresponding to the initial [`seeking`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeking_event) event and final [`seeked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeked_event) event for each "seek" interaction (media timeline position adjustment — more on that below).

> Note: this would be a great case for using the [observable](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable) pattern, but that's not (yet ) part of the language.

Here's a minimal example showing how to correlate the start and end times for each seek interaction:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAshAmBLAhgSQHbAgJ2QY2EQHt0AVRAWwgGdhkKwoBeKAbwCgooB6AKl6gZgUALRQAqgDlUADSgVEAG0WJqEPCXjUovbpyh5FRPAGsAXFHQBXCgCMcAbn18BAMSPJhYgMrrN23X0qJGQLaztHdgBfJ3YXKABRdGorbGhgAAtPKEycCABybWzFCGRaKBJoACJaZGxgKqhkdHgoKogWxogSqkwoRHQcjOg63BAdPQAzK3QCYkGytXqAQWwxgBkOgHNMgHE0zxxSLPQAeXQIAB5SAD4ACn1RiwP4EkVx0gBtAF0AGnYAJQWRY4YBFNb9bQvN7jT6kX5QeFQAB0qK+32+Tmms0IJCa1CWwFWG22ewOWGwx2a5yutweXCeiJ+-yB+MJ4OwkKgcIRSNRyPRmPY2LmeJBKzWyBAm3QOwy+1KFKpZwu13ujOh6HeTO+ALY+kQkygd1GyJKssyUEuUAATHqOFwuJlsEQAO6WCDuhJrIjYemOrgAAwSAA9IAQEE1JeNzXKoFtyTghs0oABGKC2KzCSZEGatAAkrFNscyUUD-wDAKcXCi0XYcW4UAAmrnOXhkMpbPgTFBACgEUFeUFdWSwADckyBc0PmsJhmkzA2oBBkVtkQOILZc7MIAj8HgbFZFIcEWAXXgaNQT0RysAiFAluPsAiIMA8MjhTNRYMTvASr4ICY5BULUDDUP6hDAXQoHPKUrxauMcAhEIOD4LiZCUDQUFgMygIWKORCIK0DpsqCxJSjKcoKoclInDSdwQZh9BgNQVb6BoyTZog2DlCwDEgcxyKeHcAAMAIAITVgYJDlEePE5Bh-HUIJwB3CIqbiZJ7HUEQJRmkQWx3KwUCTFxtAIrJwAInxWHaFErG1uwWnCKOhEQHeLCvPuvTAMiACOVg4CAvglAQvp3FULnwG5VSsYaxpiZFbl6s6boel6Pp+lUABqrl3t0EDeZYRDZlu8AxbETnxi+QGMQwzDGqyiEoMhuBfjV-HMDcxrEYYxjmFAAAihzIugbp3ACFbyAgKB4blyL7msHTADV-x2bEJTCGoAHtTZFhNWgmAoW1ClYT89U-LE3CNgAEs0v7QKN6AiO0nT3hAAFLuOmDUAuiVEIJ8DwAkX3AOsqhYBcmVbSYAxbFUCLjZ1b3bSdTFKWAVjUBkdxbNVqMMONAKsYut0tCUbQdGVyM9hAIM-ewf0A0DINg7QHQ4OF0MIPDDVIz10nCGCSStCwuPLfjYDjZpAtQEY7aKPV0M7WjklKxL2gsBd+hyx2yIY1j9HUMLrFcD+f7vYB6t3Drij2axQA)

```js
/** Ensure that there's at least one "start" and "end" element in the array */
function assertArrayLengthGreaterThanOne(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    throw new Error(
      `Expected array length greater than 1 but found ${arr.length}`,
    );
  }
}

// Your callback — do whatever you want here:
// e.g. debounce, accumulate, process, post to server, etc.
function handleSeekTimestamps(timestamps) {
  assertArrayLengthGreaterThanOne(timestamps);
  const first = timestamps.at(0);
  const last = timestamps.at(-1);
  console.log({ first, last, timestamps });
}

const video = document.querySelector("video");
if (!video) throw new Error("Video element not found");

const getTimestamp = () => ({
  clock: Date.now(),
  media: video.currentTime,
});

let seekTimestamps = [];

// Handle non-"end" seek events:
video.addEventListener("seeking", () => seekTimestamps.push(getTimestamp()));

// Handle "end" seek events:
video.addEventListener("seeked", () => {
  const tsEnd = getTimestamp();
  const local = seekTimestamps;
  seekTimestamps = [];
  local.push(tsEnd);
  handleSeekTimestamps(local);
});
```

Here's a link to a demonstration (https://jsfiddle.net/yp2dLsf9/) — the embedded video was too large for a Stack Overflow code snippet and I didn't want to link to a media resource because of link rot. (Ironic, I know.)

Exactly when the events fire during timeline adjustment is already debounced to some extent — however, this behavior is controlled by the user agent (browser) and not completely defined by the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-seeking), which means that if you desire exact debounce timing, you'll have to implement that separately. [*Debouncing* has already been covered extensively on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+debounce), and covering it again here isn't appropriate (we strive to have focused questions and answers on SO, and to discourage duplicate content).

As you can see in the code above, you can capture not just the start and end time values, but also the ones in between. You can also capture clock timestamp information — this seems quite useful in context of the nature of the analytics data you're seeking to collect because it allows for further correlations.